Cassandra partition Strategy By Date When Record Inserts are variable
I have a table that captures signals from a time series stream processor, the partition key's used are the signal id, and the date. This means that a partition is created for each signal type every day. The question I am thinking is at times a signal type might trigger thousands and thousands of times a day going over the recommended partition size and then other signal types might only trigger a couple of times a day. With this variable in signal type writes, is it over kill to put every thing into hourly bucket partitions if i do that, my queries get harder as searching for signals across hours requires more complex coding row size of a signal is not big any help on modeling strategy would be appreciated.

I don't think it would be overkill to add buckets based on the "busiest" signal type. As long as you are modelling your data based on the how the application will query the table, it is what it is.
Another approach is to use a timestamp column as the third clustering key so you can simply page through the rows regardless of how many there are. For example:
CREATE TABLE signals_by_id_date (
    signal_id int,
    signal_date date,
    signal_tstamp timestamp,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY((signal_id, signal_date), signal_tstamp)
)

